# GRAV CMS JSON Needs

Tags: angularjs, json, grav

So I am building a grav/angular combo blog, and it is really coming along well. I am using the Grav Pages as Data plugin (3rd party I know) and it outputs nearly everything I need, but it is missing a few key items for children; such as the child URL and the summary. I found a way around the summary (though I don't LOVE it). Is there another way for me to get this data via a JSON feed(s)? I am looking over the docs and it seems like there is, but I am running in circles a bit with it.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind answered my own question. I simply used the folder structure to ensure the pages url was the same as the title, and then used Angular filters to replace the white space in the title with a -. Not exactly elegant but it got the job done.

Big props to @a8m for coming up with a great library of filters! Everyone should check them out..big time saver!

https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter